# hover on div does work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox4

I have this code:

```
<div title="" class="icePnlGrp graButtonActionDiv graButtonBackgroundOn">
       <label id="j_id89:j_id99" class="iceOutLbl graButtonActionLabel">Select</label>
</div>
```

With css:

```
.graButtonBackgroundOn {
line-height: 45px;
background:
    url('/resources/images/external/button_generic_on_txmart.png');
```

}

and

```
.graButtonBackgroundOn:hover{
background:
    url('/resources/images/external/button_generic_on_txmart-hover.png');
```

}

I cannot figure out why on Firefox and IE, hovering on that div does not change the background image.... But on Chrome it works perfectly.

Can you please give me a helping hand?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it supported in IE and Firefox.

Comment: it's work for may be there is animage path problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try giving the :hover style rule more specificity over its normal state, so:

```
.graButtonBackgroundOn {
line-height: 45px;
background:
    url('/resources/images/external/button_generic_on_txmart.png');
}
div.graButtonBackgroundOn:hover{
background:
    url('/resources/images/external/button_generic_on_txmart-hover.png');
}
```

which will over write the original style rule

Comment: Simply unbelievable...Your solution works... Very strange because this: http://jsfiddle.net/DnUXF/1/ , which is using my initial post with some random images, works in FF also..