# On mouseover the icon is not changing in firefox

Tags: extjs4

I have designed a tool bar where buttons are there,. My requirement is initially it should display one icon and on mouse over the icon should change. For this i have given a class to the button and applied css for this and for hover property applied cssclass:hover with different image. For Example

```
.cssclass {
  background-image: someimage.jpg
}

.cssclass:hover {
   background-image: someotherimage.jpg
}
```

By this in all browser (chrome and IE) it is working but in Firefox the image is not changing.

Can anybody have any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks
Tapaswini

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225969/hover-on-div-does-work-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

If this is related to ExtJS 4, then you should be adding a overCls like so:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
    cls: 'normalcls',
    overCls: 'someovercls',  // right here!
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    handler: function() {
        alert('You clicked the button!');
    }
});
```

Depending on the ExtJS version, it may apply a prefix of 'x-' to the class name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One more way is while defining the css property for overcls class we can specify like
.x-over .cssclass {
   background-image: someotherimage.jpg
} This is supporting in all browser

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.  However, in case of the base prefix changing, you would be better off with this: overCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'over cssclass'